# Readers can't view my pages/post whitout logging in?

Tags: views, troubleshooting

I don't know what I did wrong but public can only access my front page. Once you click on another page you are ask to log in. I think this is a new issue and maybe due to wrong setting somewhere. But I'm really new to wordpress and I have no idea where to look !

Here is the website : riversoflife.co.za

Any idea how to resolve this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of your plugins may be causing an issue. So one suggestion would be to try disabling all plugins, then if the problem has disappeared you can try enabling the plugins one by one until you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Karen said you should try disabling plugins untill it works again.

Have you installed a plugin like "Force Login"?
Since when do you get this error ?